# Error: Compile Error: expecting a semi-colon, found '(' at line 18 column 22

Tags: apex

As noted in the title I get the following error whenever I try to save this code:

> Error: Compile Error: expecting a semi-colon, found '(' at line 18 column 22

```
public class multiselect {
    public List < selectoption > selectedoptions {get;set;}
    public List < selectoption > nonselectedoptions {get;set;}
    public List < string > cities {get;set;}
    public set < string > selectedcities {get;set;}
    public set < string > nonselectedcities {get;set;}
    public List < string > selected {get;set;}
    public List < string > removed {get;set;}
    public multiselect() {
      selectedoptions = new List < selectoption > ();
      nonselectedoptions = new List < selectoption > ();
      cities = new List < string > {'Hyd','Bang','che','pune'};
      selectedcities = new set < string > ();
      nonselectedcities = new set < string > ();
      selected = new List < string > ();
      removed = new List < string > ();
      nonselectedcities.addAll(cities);
      public void getOptions() {
       selectedoptions.clear();
       nonselectedoptions.clear();
       for (string s1: nonselectedcities) {
        selectoption op1 = new selectoption(s1, s1);
        nonselectedoptions.add(op1);
       }
       for (string s2: selectedcities) {
        selectoption op2 = new selectoption(s2, s2);
        selectedoptions.add(op2);
       }
      }
      public void addOptions() {
       selectedcities.addAll(selected);
       nonselectedcities.removeAll(selected);
       getOptions();
      }
      public void removeOptions() {
       nonselectedcities.addAll(removed);
       selectedcities.removeAll(removed);
       getOptions();
      }
}
```

Comment: you are declaring methods inside constructor. Close constructor '}' at line 18.

Comment: nonselectedcities.addAll(cities);
}
public void getOptions(){

Answer (score 3):

I believe you forgot to close your method after this line

`nonselectedcities.addAll(cities);`

Please add a '}' after this line.

```
public class multiselect{
    public List<selectoption> selectedoptions{get;set;}
    public List<selectoption> nonselectedoptions{get;set;}
    public List<string> cities{get;set;}
    public set<string> selectedcities{get;set;}
    public set<string> nonselectedcities{get;set;}
    public List<string> selected{get;set;}
    public List<string> removed{get;set;}
    public multiselect(){
        selectedoptions = new List<selectoption>();
        nonselectedoptions = new List<selectoption>();
        cities = new List<string>{'Hyd','Bang','che','pune'};
            selectedcities = new set<string>();
        nonselectedcities = new set<string>();
        selected = new List<string>();
        removed = new List<string>();
        nonselectedcities.addAll(cities);
    }
    public void getOptions(){
        selectedoptions.clear();
        nonselectedoptions.clear();
        for(string s1:nonselectedcities){
            selectoption op1 = new selectoption(s1,s1);
            nonselectedoptions.add(op1);
        }
        for(string s2:selectedcities){
            selectoption op2 = new selectoption(s2,s2);
            selectedoptions.add(op2);
        }
    }
    public void addOptions(){
        selectedcities.addAll(selected);
        nonselectedcities.removeAll(selected);
        getOptions();
    }
    public void removeOptions(){
        nonselectedcities.addAll(removed);
        selectedcities.removeAll(removed);
        getOptions();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class multiselect
{
    public List < selectoption > selectedoptions {get;set;}
    public List < selectoption > nonselectedoptions {get;set;}
    public List < string > cities {get;set;}
    public set < string > selectedcities {get;set;}
    public set < string > nonselectedcities {get;set;}
    public List < string > selected {get;set;}
    public List < string > removed {get;set;}
    public multiselect() {
    selectedoptions = new List < selectoption > ();
    nonselectedoptions = new List < selectoption > ();
    cities = new List < string > {'Hyd','Bang','che','pune'};
    selectedcities = new set < string > ();
    nonselectedcities = new set < string > ();
    selected = new List < string > ();
    removed = new List < string > ();
    nonselectedcities.addAll(cities);
}
public void getOptions()
{
    selectedoptions.clear();
    nonselectedoptions.clear();
    for (string s1: nonselectedcities) {
    selectoption op1 = new selectoption(s1, s1);
    nonselectedoptions.add(op1);
}
    for (string s2: selectedcities)
    {
        selectoption op2 = new selectoption(s2, s2);
        selectedoptions.add(op2);
    }
}
public void addOptions()
{
    selectedcities.addAll(selected);
    nonselectedcities.removeAll(selected);
    getOptions();
}
public void removeOptions()
{
    nonselectedcities.addAll(removed);
    selectedcities.removeAll(removed);
    getOptions();
}
```

You defined methods inside constructor which was causing problem.